# jboss shows error when strating from eclipse

Tags: jboss

when i starts jboss from eclipse server tab it shows an error

==========================================================================

```
18:28:50,543 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=SARDeployer state=Create: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.JAXPDeployer$1.setFeature(JAXPDeployer.java:168)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.JAXPDeployer$1.setFeature(JAXPDeployer.java:165)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.UnmarshallerFactoryDeployer.start(UnmarshallerFactoryDeployer.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_17]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_17]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:60) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:168) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]
    at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:257) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:125) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:72) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.LifecycleAction.installActionInternal(LifecycleAction.java:202) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:894) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:641) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deployBean(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:319) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deployBeans(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:297) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deploy(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:130) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.BasicKernelDeployer.deploy(BasicKernelDeployer.java:76) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.mc.deployer.TempBasicXMLDeployer.deploy(TempBasicXMLDeployer.java:92) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-mc.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.mc.deployer.TempBasicXMLDeployer.deploy(TempBasicXMLDeployer.java:193) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-mc.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.mc.server.AbstractMCServerBase.bootstrapMcAndDescriptors(AbstractMCServerBase.java:335) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-mc.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.mc.server.AbstractMCServerBase.doStart(AbstractMCServerBase.java:282) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-mc.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.as.server.AbstractJBossASServerBase.doStart(AbstractJBossASServerBase.java:381) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-as.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:413) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_17]

Failed to boot JBoss:
java.lang.Exception: Encountered exception in server startup
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.mc.server.AbstractMCServerBase.bootstrapMcAndDescriptors(AbstractMCServerBase.java:350)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.mc.server.AbstractMCServerBase.doStart(AbstractMCServerBase.java:282)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.as.server.AbstractJBossASServerBase.doStart(AbstractJBossASServerBase.java:381)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:413)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incompletely deployed:

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "SARDeployer" is in error due to: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V

    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.internalValidate(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:278)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.validate(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:174)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.mc.server.AbstractMCServerBase.bootstrapMcAndDescriptors(AbstractMCServerBase.java:339)
    ... 4 more
Posting Shutdown Request to the server...
Server startup has not completed, so halting the process
```

Would someone please be kind enough to point me towards my stupid mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Jboss comes with its own version of some XML libs and is causing the JDK parser lookup mechanism to pick the wrong one.

You will have to explicitly tell JBoss which class file has to be referenced to pick the right class.
Below is the JBoss class loading mechanism:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7